# No SAGA folder in processing options dialog box

Tags: qgis-2, saga

I am using QGIS 2.18. I am facing this error while using EasyAHP:

> "The error occured during calculation. Please make sure that
>   Processing Toolbox's SAGA provider is installed."

But, I guess the correct version of SAGA is installed, but it is not able to recognize the path.

[image]

There is no textbox to enter the path.
What should I do now?